# RStudio .rmd documnet read data source from environment when knitting

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I have a very large data source. I am creating .RMD document with charts etc. Is it possible to read the data source from the environment without have to load it each time I knit the document.

[image]

````
---
title: "test"
date: "February 10, 2017"
output: html_document
---

Data Source in environment

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data,aes(x=mpg))+geom_histogram()
```
````

Would caching work for a very large data source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to load the data "data" to your .RMD file:

1. Don't knit your file with the Rstudio "knit" button:

   ```
   library(knitr)
   knit('your_file.Rmd')
   ```

This will take your recent environment into account and the error should be gone.

2. Store your "data" as "data.RData" and load it manually in your RMD file

   ````
   ```{r load data, include=FALSE}
   load("data.RData")
   ```
   ````

   If you do it this way you can use the "knit" button from RStudio.

I hope one of this ways is a good solution for you.